# How to add a tab with menu items in Material UI ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am designing a **Navbar** using **Material UI** and **React**. I want to add a `<Tab>` in which after clicking on it, two `<MenuItems>` would be open, and each of them would redirect us to different pages.

Here is my whole code:

```
const tabs = [
    {
        label: "Dahsboard",
        value: 1,
        icon: <MdDashboard style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "1.2rem " }}/>,
        route: "/home/Dashboard/",
    },
    {
        label: "Profile",
        value: 2,
        icon: <MdAccountCircle style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "1.2rem " }}/>,
        route: "/home/Inbox/",
    },
    {
        label: "Inbox",
        value: 3,
        icon: <MdInbox style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "1.2rem " }}/>,
        route: "/home/Inbox/",
    },
]



const Nabar = (props) => {
    const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = useState(null);
    const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = useState(null);
    const [notifBadgeContent, setNotifBadgeContent] = useState(100);
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(
        props.selectedTab ? props.selectedTab : 1
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedTab(props.selectedTab);
    }, [props.selectedTab]);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        props.handleTabChange(newValue);
    };

    const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
        setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
        setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
        setAnchorElNav(null);
    };

    const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
        setAnchorElUser(null);
    }

    const onNotifBadgeClick = () => {
        if (notifBadgeContent) {
            setNotifBadgeContent(null);
        }
        else {
            setNotifBadgeContent(100);
        }
    };

    return (
        <AppBar sx={{ backgroundColor: "#E55405"}}  position="static">
            <Container maxWidth="xl">
                <Toolbar disableGutters>
                    <Box sx={{ 
                        flexGrow: 1, 
                        display: {xs: "flex", lg: "none"},
                        height: "4.5rem"
                        }}
                    >
                    <IconButton
                        size="large"
                        aria-label="user-profile"
                        aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        color="inherit"
                        onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                        >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                        <Menu
                            id="menu-appbar"
                            anchorOrigin={{
                                vertical: "top",
                                horizental: "right",
                            }}
                            keepMounted
                            transformOrigin={{
                                vertical: "bottom",
                                horizental: "right"
                            }}
                            sx={{
                                display: {xs: "block", ls: "none"},
                            }}
                            open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
                            onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                            >
                            {tabs.map((page) => (
                                <MenuItem
                                    component={Link}
                                    to={page.route}
                                    key={page.value}
                                    onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                                >
                                    <Typography textAlign="center">{page.label}</Typography>
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Menu>
                    </Box>
                    <IconButton
                        style={{ marginLeft: "20rem", width: "4.1rem" }}
                        sx={{ display: {xs: "none", lg: "flex"} }}
                    >
                        <Avatar alt="NJ LOGO" src={SiteLogo} style={{ width: "100%"}}/>
                    </IconButton>

                    <Typography
                        variant="h5"
                        component="h5"
                        noWrap
                        sx={{  display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
                        style={{ marginLeft: "1rem"}}
                        className="website-name"
                    >
                        Nomad Journey
                    </Typography>
                    
                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
                    <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', lg: 'flex' } }}>
                        <Tabs
                            value={selectedTab}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            TabIndicatorProps={{
                                style: {
                                    backgroundColor: "#D97D54",
                                },
                            }}
                            aria-label="secondary tabs example"
                            >
                            {tabs.map((tab) => {
                                return (
                                    <Tab 
                                        component={Link}
                                        to={tab.route}
                                        style={{ color: "white" }}
                                        key={tab.value}
                                        label={tab.label}
                                        value={tab.value}
                                        icon={tab.icon}
                                        />
                                );
                            })}
                            <Tab 
                                component={IconButton}
                                style={{ color: "white" }}
                                label={"Settings"}
                                value={4}
                                onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}
                                icon={<MdSettingsSuggest style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "1.2rem "}} />}
                            >
                            </Tab>
                            
                        </Tabs>
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
                        <Box
                            sx={{
                                display: "flex",
                                alignItems: "center",
                                justifyContent: "center",
                            }}
                        >
                            <IconButton
                                style={{ marginLeft: -4 }}
                                onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}
                                sx={{ p: 0 }}
                                >
                                <MdKeyboardArrowDown style={{ color: "white" }} />
                            </IconButton>
                        </Box>
                        <Menu
                            sx={{ mt: "45px" }}
                            id="menu-appbar"
                            anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                            anchorOrigin={{
                            vertical: "top",
                            horizontal: "right",
                            }}
                            keepMounted
                            transformOrigin={{
                            vertical: "top",
                            horizontal: "right",
                            }}
                            open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
                            onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
                        >
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                                <Tab 
                                    component={Link}
                                    label={"Account & Settings"}
                                    value={5}
                                    key={5}
                                    icon={<MdManageAccounts style={{ color: "black", fontSize: "1.2rem "}}/>}
                                    route={"/home/Settings/AccountSettings/"}/>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem>
                                <Tab 
                                    component={Link}
                                    label={"Logout"}
                                    value={6}
                                    key={6}
                                    icon={<MdLogout style={{ color: "black", fontSize: "1.2rem "}}/>}
                                    route={"/home/"}/>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    </Box>    
                </Toolbar>
            </Container>
        </AppBar>
    )


}

export default Nabar;
```

And here is the output:
[image]
But I want to change it and attach the downward arrow to the settings tab. And after clicking on each of them the sub menu should be rendered. And the another problem is that after clicking on the first sub menu, I will not be redirected to settings page.

I will be really grateful for any help. I am just an incipient in this field, and I am not familiar with this field.